# Why does not the first invoked activity run?

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

```
Excute code
Intent intent = getFirstIntent(context);
context.startActivity(intent);
intent = getSecondIntent(context);
context.startActivity(intent);

private void Intent getFirstIntent(Context context){
  Intent intent = new Intent(context, FirstActivity.class);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  return intent;
}

private void Intent getSecondIntent(Context context){
  Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  return intent;
}
```

And I added log activity lifecycle(onCreate, onDestroy)

Below Log

SecondActivity onCreate > back key > onDestroy > FirstActivity onCreate > back key > onDestory

But I expect this process

FirstActivity onCreate > SecondActivity > onCreate > back key > onDestory > FirstActivity(onResume) > back key > onDestory

Why first call SecondActivity-onCreate? I want to call FirstActivity-onCreate

Answer (score 0):

Since you expect -

> FirstActivity onCreate > SecondActivity > onCreate > back key >
>   onDestory > FirstActivity(onResume) > back key > onDestory

You should not use any `Intent.FLAGS`

The behavior you expect is Android default behavior of `Activity`.

[Read here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) for more about Intent Flags.